# intuit payment gateway - is quickbooks needed?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-processing, intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to integrate intuit payment processing with a website. Does this require QuickBooks?

I find the directions a little confusing. Support folks seem to be a little lost. Is there a direct link to the documentation or code that I can find on intuit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, QuickBooks is not necessary.

Here is a link to Intuit's documentation:
 https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0085_QuickBooks_Windows_SDK/qbms

This is most likely the route you'll be taking if you're collecting the card information on your website, then passing it off to Intuit for the authorization/charge:
 https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0085_QuickBooks_Windows_SDK/qbms/0060_Documentation/Sending_Requests

We have some additional information on our wiki here:
 [Intuit QuickBooks Merchant Services development wiki](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbms_integration)

You'll have to go through application registration here:
 http://appreg.intuit.com/

If you want to make your life misreable, register in HOSTED mode.

If you want to actually get something working, register in DESKTOP mode.

If you're developing in PHP, we have an open-source QuickBooks PHP library that also includes support for QuickBooks Merchant Services:
 [QuickBooks PHP DevKit](http://consolibyte.com/downloads/quickbooks-php-devkit/)

If you need free support, DO NOT call them. The phone support people don't know anything about integration/technical stuff. Instead, use the forums:
 https://idnforums.intuit.com/

Comment: This is by far the best support I got on intuit. Yes, I'm working with PHP. And in the past several days I've been going through the docs online and I found it really badly presented. Too many bits and pieces and lack of flow and readability.

Comment: Yeah, their docs suck and the phone support doesn't know a thing. If you register in DESKTOP mode and look at the example code we provide, it's really pretty darn simple. Register, follow the link to get your connection ticket, plug in the values, and it works.